# Format the text in JavaScript alert box

Tags: javascript, html, format, alert

How can I format the text in a JavaScript alert box? I need a word in the text to be underlined.

Answer (score 42):

You can use only:

```
\b = Backspace 
\f = Form feed 
\n = New line 
\r = Carriage return 
\t = tab
\000 = octal character 
\x00 = hexadecimal character 
\u0000 = hexadecimal unicode character
```

So, you can insert different [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters, but not format them (like *italic* or **bold**).

**EDIT** I also have to mention, that in fact `alert` acts like `toString` conversion, so including tags and/or styles is not possible.

Comment: You can underline with unicode character `'\u0332'`; `alert('h̲e̲l̲l̲o̲');` (might not come out as a solid line, though)

Comment: @PaulS. [yep](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/xKAyH/), but it's not underline anyway

Comment: It's possible to do some interesting stuff with those [hexa numbers](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm curious what you're expecting [`\f`FormFeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed) to accomplish within an `alert`?

Answer (score 9):

Underline a string using unicode character `'\u0332'`, called a `COMBINING LOW LINE`

```
function underline(s) {
    var arr = s.split('');
    s = arr.join('\u0332');
    if (s) s = s + '\u0332';
    return s;
}

var str = underline('hello world'); // "h̲e̲l̲l̲o̲ ̲w̲o̲r̲l̲d̲"

alert(str);
```

This method is not guaranteed to produce a smooth underline.

Example of `confirm()` on Firefox 59:

[image: firefox confirm u0332]

Comment: I needed this for a prompt box to underline the Y in Yes. `Y\u0332es`. Thank you. I've just tested `var str = underline(underline('hello world'));` and it makes the underline double up if that's what anyone is after. You can also give it 3 etcetera like so: `var str = underline(underline(underline('hello world')));`

Answer (score 4):

You can not style the text inside an alert box. But you can use a modal box solution instead, here's a list to get you started:

- [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), from jQuery UI
- [Simple Modal](http://simplemodal.plasm.it)
- [leanModal](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au)
- [Reveal: jQuery Modal](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I created internationalization through a JavaScript file. I needed a mnemonic on each button so I was looking for an easy solution. Actually, I've an easy approach to get the wanted result:

`\u0332` is the Unicode Character [COMBINING LOW LINE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0332/index.htm)

With this character you can underline single letters.

Demonstration:

```js
alert('S\u0332earch - s underlined');

i18n = {};

i18n.SEARCH = "S\u0332earch - s underlined";

document.getElementById('search').innerHTML = i18n.SEARCH;
```

```html
<button id="search"></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: Browsers have started to disable Unicode support in their native dialogs, so this is a dead end.

---

As two answers suggest the solution is to use Unicode, but you have to do this properly! I also wanted a more reusable solution where I would not need to reinvent the wheel each and every time. So I came up with [this small JavaScript function](https://github.com/davidkonrad/toUnicodeVariant) for convenience.

```js
alert('Really need to alert some '+toUnicodeVariant('underlined', 'bold sans', 'underline')+' text');
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/davidkonrad/toUnicodeVariant/master/toUnicodeVariant.js"></script>
```

Should produce something like this in all major browsers (try run the code snippet above) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
Use external lib as [JQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or your own implementation.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. You'd have to use a plugin. If you have jQuery installed there's a bunch to choose from. If not this one looks promising: http://simplemodal.plasm.it/#examples