# How Best to Copy Formatted Text Into Clipboard

Tags: javascript

I know that there are a million posts on how to copy a javascript variable into a clipboard. I'm partial to this approach:

```
window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", output);
```

However, I'm wondering how I can get a variable that contains bold. My desired result is that I can paste the variable (into word) and have a portion of it bolded. I'm trying to set up up the variable like this:

```
var output = "something <b>bold section</b> something else";
```

I don't want to export that literally with the HTML, I want to export it as though I selected and then copied the following:

something **bold section** something else

How can I best achieve this result?

Comment: [somehow related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470817/format-the-text-in-javascript-alert-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470817/format-the-text-in-javascript-alert-box) style the prompt window.

But a possible way, for [*recent* browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection#Browser_compatibility) (IE9+), is to use the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) instead of the `prompt()` trick :

```js
btn.onclick = function() {
  // create a modal
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = "something <b>bold section</b> something else";
  document.body.appendChild(p);
  // create a new range of our message
  var range = document.createRange();
  // get the textNodes
  var nodes = p.childNodes;
  // start our range at first node
  range.setStart(nodes[0], 0);
  // end it at last
  range.setEnd(nodes[nodes.length - 1], nodes[nodes.length - 1].length);
  // create a Selection object
  var sel = getSelection();
  // remove existing ranges
  sel.removeAllRanges()
  // set our new one
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">show the text to copy</button>
```