# Formating in Alert Message with addition of image

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to achieve formatting of text in JS alert message?

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
alert("1.Enter your name. 2. Enter your mobile no. 3.Do not press back 
button.");
}
</script>
```

I want these 3 messages to appear one below the other. I tried:

```
<p>1.Enter your name.</p><p> 2. Enter your mobile no.</p><p> 3.Do not
press back button.</p>
```

Didn't work. Also, wish to add this img src tag after the last message:

```
<img src="http://forums.nextgames.com/resources/emoji/smiley.png" alt="smily"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470817/format-the-text-in-javascript-alert-box . You should consider using Bootstrap modals or jQuery UI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [format the text in javascript alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470817/format-the-text-in-javascript-alert-box)

Answer (score 1):

The alert box is a  object, and not related to CSS. To do this style of thing you would need to create an HTML element and mimic the alert() functionality. The jQuery UI Modal box does a lot of the work for you.

Comment: You can use modals for this...as you want

Answer (score 1):

try adding "/n" before the lines  example "\n2", "\n3"

Answer (score 0):

The browser alert box does not support rendering HTML, however you *can* use plain-text formatting like `\n` newline and `\t` tab.

```
alert("1.Enter your name.\n2. Enter your mobile no.\n3.Do not press back button.");
```

Comment: You should teach a man how to fish. There is answer for this question since 2013.

Comment: What about the img src tag? How to add that?

Comment: @Chetan You can't.